# Kendo DropDownList default selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropDownList:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("concessions")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px" })
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("getConcessionsDDL", "MasterData");
        });
    })
)
```

The datasource is read from the `getConcessionsDDL` method, in the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetConcessionsDDL()
{
    ConcessionModel cm = new ConcessionModel();
    var aux = cm.getConcessions();
    return Json(aux.concessions.Select(sme => new ConcessionModel { Description = sme.concession.mediumDescription, Id = sme.concession.id }).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It works fine, the DropDownList is populated as expected. But now I want define its default selected value. As it is now, the default value is always the first of the list.

I have used `.SelectedIndex(4)` and it works: the selected index will be 4, in this case. But I want to define this in the controller.

I have tried to pass the selected index in a `ViewBag` but no luck:

```
ViewBag.selectedIndex = 21;
```

And in the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("concessions")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px" })
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("getConcessionsDDL", "MasterData");
        });
    })
    .SelectedIndex(ViewBag.selectedIndex)
)
```

No luck so far. Any help?

Comment: shouldn't be .SelectedIndex(ViewBag.selectedIndex) ?  ViewBag. selectedIndex not ViewBag.SelectedIndex

Comment: Well noted but `ViewBag` values aren't case sensitive so, `ViewBag.selectedIndex` = `ViewBag.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Why not just rename the kendo dropdown list to something in your viewmodel (e.g. your 'Id' property)? This way the selectedindex will be automatically set, rather than passing in through viewbag.

Comment: @kryptonkal, you mean `.Name("Id")`? I don't see how that would bind the id value to the Road model as there are many id's. The `getConcessionsDDL` method brings all the concessions from the database, unbound to any other model.

Comment: You are offering the user to select a Concession, then why not have a ConcessionId property within your viewmodel. Just use that as your control name and assign the property when the page loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple, adding the value as an HTML attribute works fine:

`.HtmlAttributes(new { value = ViewBag.ConcessionId })`

Like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("concessions")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px" })
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { value = ViewBag.ConcessionId })
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("getConcessionsDDL", "MasterData");
        });
    })
)
```